# @Select with Int values in Scala Temlate

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm using play-2.0.3.
I have a Map  and  want to populate dropdown-list with Int->String ( using something like @select).
 I know that @select accepts only Seq[(String, String).
  How can I overload this helper to accept Seq[(Int, String)] ?

#### I have tried to do the following:

1. Copied source of the select.scala.html to views/mySelect.scala.html
2. Edited it for my purposes.

```scala
@**
* Generate an HTML select.
*
* Example:
* {{{
* @select(field = myForm("isDone"), options = options("Yes","No"))
* }}}
*
* @param field The form field.
* @param args Set of extra attributes.
* @param handler The field constructor.
*@
@import helper._

@(field: Field, options: Seq[(Int,String)], args: (Symbol,Any)*)(implicit handler: FieldConstructor, lang: play.api.i18n.Lang)

@input(field, args:_*) { (id, name, value, htmlArgs) =>
    <select id="@id" name="@name" @toHtmlArgs(htmlArgs)>
    @args.toMap.get('_default).map { defaultValue =>
        <option class="blank" value="">@defaultValue</option>
    }
    @options.map { v =>
        <option value="@v._1" @(if(value == Some(v._1)) "selected" else "")>@v._2</option>
    }
    </select>
}
```

But it seems no to work.

Play says

```
')' expected but identifier found.
```

in the line

```
@(field: Field, options: Seq[(Int,String)], args: (Symbol,Any)*)(implicit handler: FieldConstructor, lang: play.api.i18n.Lang)
```

By the way what is *  for after  the **(Symbol,Any)** ?
Play doesn't like it.
Even if I delete this *****, then play says:

```
 not found: value field
```

refering the same line.

Help me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution.

```
@**
* file views/mySelect.scala.html 
*
* Generate an HTML select.
*
* Example:
* {{{
* @select(field = myForm("isDone"), options = options("Yes","No"))
* }}}
*
* @param field The form field.
* @param args Set of extra attributes.
* @param handler The field constructor.
*@


@(field: Field, listOptions: Map[Integer,String], args: (Symbol,Any)*)(implicit handler: views.html.helper.FieldConstructor, lang: play.api.i18n.Lang)
@import helper._
@input(field, args:_*) { (id, name, value, htmlArgs) =>
    <select id="@id" name="@name" @toHtmlArgs(htmlArgs)>
    @args.toMap.get('_default).map { defaultValue =>
        <option class="blank" value="">@defaultValue</option>
    }
    @listOptions.map { v =>
        <option value="@v._1" @(if(value == Some(v._1)) "selected" else "")>@v._2</option>
    }
    </select>
}
```

- **(Symbol,Any)*** means "Treat as vararg parameter".  You use it when you have a variable argument function, like

  ```
  def varargfunc( argument : T* ) ...
  ```
- now we can

  ```
  @import mySelect
  ```

  and use it like

  ```
  @mySelect(
      userForm("room"), 
      rooms, @* Map<Integer, String>* rooms*@ 
      '_default -> Messages.get("chooseRoom"),
      '_showConstraints -> false
      )
  ```
- Yes, we should use **@import** only after function declaration (in function's body).
- Don't use variable name

  ```
  options: Map[Integer,String]
  ```

  along with

  ```
  @import helper._
  ```

  Because it causes ambiguous sense of **options**, as it is also a function from **views.html.helper**

Answer (score 1):

Remove "@import helper._" . Every scala template file is a function in the background. The "@(field: Field, options: Seq[(Int,String)], args: (Symbol,Any)*)(implicit handler: FieldConstructor, lang: play.api.i18n.Lang)" line must be the first line.